# Posting SpecFlow results to TestRail

Tags: c#, json, specflow, testrail

Disclaimer: I am a relative coding novice who is learning on the job.

I have setup a Specflow project for using Cucumber and C# Selenium and downloaded the TestRail API. I followed an existing example to post a test result to a static Test Rail ID at the end of a Scenario.

```
{
    Gurock.TestRail.APIClient client = new Gurock.TestRail.APIClient("https://testrail.placeholder.com/testrail");
    client.User = "user@email.com"; //Put the e-mail of your user here
    client.Password = "password"; //Put the password of your user here

    Dictionary<string, object> testResult = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    if (null != ScenarioContext.Current.TestError)
    {
        testResult["status_id"] = "5"; //failed;
        testResult["comment"] = ScenarioContext.Current.TestError.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        testResult["status_id"] = "1"; //passed
    }

    client.SendPost("add_result_for_case/:run_id/:case_id"); //Here I am using a hardcoded test id.
}
```

I can link the above code to a Scenario by using an If based on the Scenario Tag, e.g.

```
if (ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("case_id"))
```

but the problem with this is that I would have to duplicate the above code for every scenario, with a unique IF statement and tag each time. What I would like is a way to parametrise the posting, so that I only need one block of code that enables me to send the results of each scenario to the correct static TestRail ID.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefix the CaseID Tags, so that you can differentiate them from normal tags.
Lets say with TC_, so that your tags are named like TC_1, TC_42, ...

To get now the test case id, you have to find one entry that starts with TC_ in the `ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags`

The code for this could look like:

```
var tags = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags;
var testCaseIds = tags
                    .Where(i => i.StartsWith("TC_")) //get all entries that start with TC_
                    .Select(i => i.Substring(3)); //get only the part after TC_
                    .ToList();
```

Now you have a list with the test case ids, that can you pass to the TestRails API.